# vue3: the value of the ref to component in setup() puzzle me

Tags: vue.js

My project is based on Vue3 and I use the component called 'el-tree' provided by 'element-plus'. For accessing  I define a variable called 'tree' which value is ref(null) in setup() method. Then I wrote an attribute ref called 'tree' in 'el-tree' in my template code.

I think that the ref value of 'tree' in the whole setup() method is null. But why it has value when I log it in the callback function of promise.

**template**

```html
<template>
<el-card>
    <el-tree
        :data="menuTreeList"
        show-checkbox
        default-expand-all
        node-key="id"
        ref="tree"
        highlight-current
        :props="defaultProps">
    </el-tree>
</el-card>
</template>
```

**setup() method**

```js
setup(){
    ...
    const tree = ref(null)
    const puzzleValue = function(){
        console.log(tree.value) // null
        Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
            console.log(tree.value) //Proxy{}
        })
    }
    puzzleValue()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `tree` right after defining it but before the component is created, that's why it is still not a `Proxy`. All your `ref` will become `Proxy` after your components are created. That is why you can see the change in value when the promise resolves.

In order for this to not happen, you should make sure to never access your refs right after defining them in the `setup` function. Use always a lifecycle hook for that:

```js
setup(){
  const tree = ref(null)
  const puzzleValue = function(){
      console.log(tree.value)
      Promise.resolve().then(()=> {
          console.log(tree.value)
      })
  }

  onMounted(() => puzzleValue()) // now, tree.value will be a Proxy consistently
}
```